# android - Firebase notification not receiving in Android 9.1

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I've a phone with android 9.1 . the problem is that it's not receiving firebase notification . I've tested exactly the same app on other phones and they did work fine but in this particular version it's not working .

this is my code

```
public class FCMService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "this";

@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        sendMessageToActivity(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
}

private void sendMessageToActivity(String body) {
    .......
}
```

}

again , it working fine in other version like android 8 or even android 9 but not in android 9.1

this is the screen of phone about :

[image]

Comment: Hi! When this happens? Your app is in foreground, is closed or is killed?

Answer (score 2):

If the application is in foreground or active in background (not visible but available on the task manager) it receives notifications.

So, Kindly check If your application is "closed/killed" on android 9.0 no notification is received.

Comment: Firebase cloud messaging uses Google play services to send notification, so the notification is being received even if app is killed. Only on certain android custom roms this feature isn't handled by the creator of the rom. This is a Huawei so I think this is not the problem